# gradle distribution lib exclude

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I used to gradle.
If I build, zip file is created in the build / distributions.
look at the zip file list consists of the bin and lib.
bin folder has a batch file, lib folder has a jar and dll files.
lib folder is like this:
test.jar
a.dll
b.dll
jna-4.1.0.jar
jna-platform-4.1.0.jar
samplefile.jar
I want to create a folder under the lib folder to the dll, dll files is located.

My build.gradle file is like this.

```
project('test'){
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'application'
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    flatDir{
        dirs '../library'
    }
}
distributions {
  main{
    contents{
      into('lib'){
      }
      into('lib/dll'){
      }
    }
  }
}
dependencies {
    compile name: 'jna-4.1.0' 
    compile name: 'jna-platform-4.1.0' 
    compile name: 'samplefile'
    runtime files(file('../library/dll'))
}
```